# Youtube Api v3 multiple video duration

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api

I am using Youtube Api v3 to search for videos. I would like to receive videos has duration between 0-20 minutes.

```
SearchResource.ListRequest listRequest = SearchResource.List("snippet");
 listRequest.Q = query;
 listRequest.Type = "video";
 listRequest.VideoDuration =    SearchResource.ListRequest.VideoDurationEnum.Medium;
```

Youtube has enum which defines lengths like;

```
SearchResource.ListRequest.VideoDurationEnum.Short; (0-4 minutes)
SearchResource.ListRequest.VideoDurationEnum.Medium; (4-20 minutes)
```

I would like to merge those 2 filters into one. Because Medium filter does not return videos between 0-4 minutes.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: don't know anything about the youtube api, but does `listRequest.VideoDuration =    SearchResource.ListRequest.VideoDurationEnum.Short | SearchResource.ListRequest.VideoDurationEnum.Medium;` work? Otherwise you need to make 2 ListRequests

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. It takes whatever first enum is defined. And compiler gives warning  that says "bitwise operation on enum which is not marked by flags attribute"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as I read the documentation, I do not see an elegant way to do it. So create 2 requests, merge the lists and iterate over them. Something like this:

```
// define 2 separate requests
SearchResource.ListRequest listRequestMedium = SearchResource.List("snippet");
listRequestMedium.Q = query;
listRequestMedium.Type = "video";
listRequestMedium.VideoDuration = SearchResource.ListRequest.VideoDurationEnum.Medium;
SearchResource.ListRequest listRequestShort = SearchResource.List("snippet");
listRequestShort.Q = query;
listRequestShort.Type = "video";
listRequestShort.VideoDuration = SearchResource.ListRequest.VideoDurationEnum.Short;

SearchListResponse shortVideos = listRequestShort.Fetch();
SearchListResponse mediumVideos = listRequestMedium.Fetch();

// merge the 2 result lists and iterate over them
foreach (SearchResult searchResult in shortVideos.Items.Union(mediumVideos.Items).ToList()) {
    // do something with the videos

}
```